# mysql left join

Tags: mysql

I have two table one is index and another is the price structure as under

```
table: index
columns: trandate, indexcode

table: price
Columns: truncate, symbol, price
```

I want to know the missing price. For that I issue the query:

```
select i.trandate,i.indexcode,p.trandate,p.price 
  from index i 
  left join price p on i.trandate = p.trandate 
 where p.symbol='ABC' and indexcode="New"
```

The above query does not show the null date even though various price in missing in price table. Only reason i understand is that the index table does not have the symbol field that's why...but as per theory if you want to show all the rows of one table and only the match value of another table then use the left or right join query...please  anybody can help?

Comment: This is a poorly framed question. Please be specific when you create your question title.

Comment: indexcode="New" Should be a i.indexcode?? A typo Error?? and is trandate of type DATETIME or only DATE ?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and actual/expected results?

Answer (score 1):

if you do this

```
where p.symbol='ABC' and indexcode="New"
```

you only get hits that conform to that. So they all must have a symbol that is 'ABC'. Now I'm not sure why you expect your NULL values to be present if you do this, but I think you mean this?

```
 where (p.symbol='ABC' OR p.symbol IS NULL) and indexcode="New"
```

Comment: I past the result required and query generated                     Required result   
Date INDEXCODE Trandate Price
29-Mar-92 new 29-Mar-92 61.9
30-Mar-92 new  null         Null
31-Mar-92 new 31-Mar-92 61.9
Current query give the following result   
29-Mar-92 new 29-Mar-92 61.9
31-Mar-92 new 31-Mar-92 61.9

Comment: That's kinda unreadable? could you paste that in your question, using code tags and all?

Answer (score 1):

you have to move the conditions concerning the `left join`ed table to the `left join` `ON` part:

```
select i.trandate,i.indexcode,p.trandate,p.price 
  from index i 
  left join price p on i.trandate = p.trandate and p.symbol='ABC'
 where indexcode="New"
```

Comment: i change the order as per your suggestion put no luck. i also add the i infront of indexcode. i paste the result required and what query is generated.

Comment: Your result shows the query actually works. You have to look for not `i.trandate` but for `p.trandate`(the 3rd column) to be `null`. If you  want to see only missing prices then add to the end of where clause: `AND p.trandate is null`. Cheers